# AC Honda DX Civic 95 not cooling button for recirc AIR unlit

Tags: honda, civic, ac

I have had an issue with a 1995 Civic cooling. It worked 2 months ago. I will try to be specific. I have studied HVAC, Compressors in Blgs, just not vehicles so I know the system somewhat.

It will NOT light up the recirculated AIR button to be Orange (some times) like yesterday + absolutely no cooling on 91 Degree day.  The Green one lit up for Outside Air. **What is the ORANGE RECIRULATED AIR button pilot light for?** Why does it turn the orange light on? Why doesn't it turn the light on?

I know you need to turn it to inside re-circulation air,and NOT mix hot outside air into vehicle. I have been wondering and asking about the pilot light for...about 17 years.
Would it indicate a problem? Would it not lighting up mean the compressor is not engaging clutch or mean anything ? If I am charging like yesterday and it will not take the R134 into low side port but spills all over the charge can and my hand is it already full of a charge ? 5-6 months ago I successfully charged it with A/C Pro / R-134a A/C pro premium.It got cool as heck,very good and compressor cycling. Now no pressure appears in the little AC Pro gauge why is that ? Should I change out the control board ? I can switch that out but hate to do it for no reason. Please if you can,help with the ORANGE Recirc. Button question, also quick method to tell (test) if control panel is scrap or relay is the culprit.

Comment: It sounds as though you didn't have the connection to the low side port correct, which caused it to spill (and also why it showed nothing on the gauge). Try it again and ensure it's on  all the way. This will tell use more about what is going on with the system. Also, test to see if the clutch is engaging by having someone else turn the A/C unit on while you are watching. Conversely, you can also jump the two wires at the pressure switch which will tell the clutch to kick on (if you have the A/C on). You don't want to do this for long, but it will tell you about the R-134a charge.